# How to create a type that is closed under inherited operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, containers, metaclass

In the mathematical sense, a set (or type) is [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) under an operation if the operation always returns a member of the set itself.

This question is about making a class that is closed under all operations inherited from its superclasses.

Consider the following class.

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass
```

Since `__add__` has not been overridden, it is not closed under addition.

```
x = MyInt(6)
print(type(x + x))  # <class 'int'>
```

One very tedious way to make the type closed would be to manually cast back the result of every operation that returns an `int` to `MyInt`.

Here, I automated that process using a metaclass, but this seems like an overly complex solution.

```
import functools

class ClosedMeta(type):
    _register = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        # A unique id for the class
        uid = max(cls._register) + 1 if cls._register else 0

        def tail_cast(f):
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                out = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if type(out) in bases:
                    # Since the class does not exist yet, we will recover it later
                    return cls._register[uid](out)
                return out
            return wrapper

        for base in reversed(bases):
            for name, attr in base.__dict__.items():
                if callable(attr) and name not in namespace:
                    namespace[name] = tail_cast(attr)

        subcls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
        cls._register[uid] = subcls
        return subcls

class ClosedInt(int, metaclass=ClosedMeta):
    pass
```

This fails on some cornercases such as `property` and methods recovered through `__getattribute__`. It also fails when the base is not composed only of base types.

For example, this fails:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

class ClosedInt(MyInt, metaclass=ClosedMeta):
    pass

ClosedInt(1) + ClosedInt(1) # returns the int 2
```

I attempted to fix this, but it just seems to go deeper and deeper in the rabbit hole.

This seems like a problem that might have some simple pythonic solution. What would be a other, neater ways to achieve such a closed type?

Comment: So, this mgiht be nitpicky, but `class BasicIntContainer(int)` is *not an int container*, it *is an int*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I might be off in my terminology, how would you call such a construct?

Comment: It is simply inheritance, an "is-a" relationship in the parlance of OOP. If you hover over the containers tag, you'll see that:  "A container is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects.". So like a `list` or a `dict`. Here, a `BasicIntContainer` instance isn't a collection of other objects, it *is a specialized kind of `int` object*. I don't want to distract from an interesting question with more terminology nitpicking. Anyway, I would just rephrase as "how to create a type that is closed under inherited operations"

Comment: You can easily write a simple decorator if you just want to cast return values to type itself, but the problem with that would be that there may be methods that wouldn't be returning values that would be able to cast to the proper type, if that is the case; you would need to distinguish them somehow, if not you can just decorate the class with a decorator that would decorate every method.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan For simplification, let's assume that the `__new__` knows how to cast from all of its superclasses. Also, this decorator solution is basicaly what I implemented with a metaclass. I am currently fixing it, but it is getting very complex and I am for sure forgetting a lot of cornercases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the idea of using a metaclass is the way to go. The trick is to cast the values dynamically when you get them instead of up front. That's basically what python is all about: not knowing quite what you'll get or what's there until you actually get it.

To do that, you have to redefine `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` on your class with some caveats:

1. Operators don't go through the normal attribute access methods. Even defining the right `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` on your metaclass won't help. Dunders have to be overridden explicitly for each class.
2. Methods returned by `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` need to have their return values cast to the target type. Same applies to dunders called as operators.
3. Some methods should be excepted from #2 to ensure proper operation of the machinery.

The same basic casting wrapper can be used for all the attribute and method return values. It just needs to recurse exactly oncewhen it's called on the result of `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__`.

The solution shown below does exactly that. It explicitly wraps all dunders that aren't listed as exceptions. All other attributes are either cast immediately or wrapped if they are functions. It allows any method to be customized by checking everything in the `__mro__`, including the class itself. The solution will work correctly with class and static methods because it stores the casting routine and doesn't rely on `type(self)` (as some of my previous attempts did). It will correctly exclude any attributes listed in `exceptions`, not just dunder methods.

```
import functools


def isdunder(x):
    return isinstance(x, str) and x.startswith('__') and x.endswith('__')


class DunderSet:
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return isdunder(x)


def wrap_method(method, xtype, cast):

    @functools.wraps(method)
    def retval(*args, **kwargs):
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)
        return cast(result) if type(result) == xtype else result

    return retval


def wrap_getter(method, xtype, cast, exceptions):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def retval(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        result = method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
        return result if name in exceptions else check_type(result, xtype, cast)

    return retval


def check_type(value, xtype, cast):
    if type(value) == xtype:
        return cast(value)
    if callable(value):
        return wrap_method(value, xtype, cast)
    return value


class ClosedMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        if 'exceptions' in kwargs:
            exceptions = set([
                '__new__', '__init__', '__del__',
                '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__subclasscheck__',
                *map(str, kwargs.pop('exceptions'))
            ])
        else:
            exceptions = DunderSet()
        target = kwargs.pop('target', bases[0] if bases else object)

        cls = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, dct, **kwargs)

        for base in cls.__mro__:
            for name, item in base.__dict__.items():
                if isdunder(name) and (base is cls or name not in dct) and callable(item):
                    if name in ('__getattribute__', '__getattr__'):
                        setattr(cls, name, wrap_getter(item, target, cls, exceptions))
                    elif name not in exceptions:
                        setattr(cls, name, wrap_method(item, target, cls))
        return cls

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args)


class MyInt(int):
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return x == self
    def my_op(self, other):
        return int(self * self // other)


class ClosedInt(MyInt, metaclass=ClosedMeta, target=int,
                exceptions=['__index__', '__int__', '__trunc__', '__hash__']):
    pass

class MyClass(ClosedInt, metaclass=type):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return 1

print(type(MyInt(1) + MyInt(2)))
print(0 in MyInt(0), 1 in MyInt(0))
print(type(MyInt(4).my_op(16)))

print(type(ClosedInt(1) + ClosedInt(2)))
print(0 in ClosedInt(0), 1 in ClosedInt(0))
print(type(ClosedInt(4).my_op(16)))

print(type(MyClass(1) + ClosedInt(2)))
```

The result is

```
<class 'int'>
True False
<class 'int'> 

<class '__main__.ClosedInt'>
True False
<class '__main__.ClosedInt'>

<class 'int'>
```

The last example is a tribute to [@wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341432/2988730). It shows that you have to *want* to do this for it to work.

IDEOne link because I don't have access to a computer right now: https://ideone.com/iTBFW3

**Appendix 1: Improved default exceptions**

I think that a better default set of exceptions than all dunder methods can be complied by looking carefully through the [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) section of the documentation. Methods can be categorized into two broad classes: methods with very specific return types that make the python machinery work, and methods whose output should be checked and wrapped when they return an instance of your type of interest. There is a third category, which is methods that should always be excepted, even when you forget to mention them explicitly.

Here is a list of the methods that are always excepted:

- `__new__`
- `__init__`
- `__del__`
- `__init_subclass__`
- `__instancecheck__`
- `__subclasscheck__`

Here is a list of everything that should be excepted by default:

- `__repr__`
- `__str__`
- `__bytes__`
- `__format__`
- `__lt__`
- `__le__`
- `__eq__`
- `__ne__`
- `__gt__`
- `__ge__`
- `__hash__`
- `__bool__`
- `__setattr__`
- `__delattr__`
- `__dir__`
- `__set__`
- `__delete__`
- `__set_name__`
- `__slots__` (not a method, but still)
- `__len__`
- `__length_hint__`
- `__setitem__`
- `__delitem__`
- `__iter__`
- `__reversed__`
- `__contains__`
- `__complex__`
- `__int__`
- `__float__`
- `__index__`
- `__enter__`
- `__exit__`
- `__await__`
- `__aiter__`
- `__anext__`
- `__aenter__`
- `__aexit__`

If we stash this list into a variable called `default_exceptions`, the class `DunderSet` can be removed entirely, and the conditional that extracts `exceptions` can be replaced by:

```
exceptions = set([
    '__new__', '__init__', '__del__',
    '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__subclasscheck__',
    *map(str, kwargs.pop('exceptions', default_exceptions))
])
```

**Appendix 2: Improved targetting**

It should be possible to target multiple types pretty easily. This is especially useful when extending other instances of `ClosedMeta`, which may not override all the methods we want.

The first step in doing this is making `target` into a container of classes instead of a single class reference. Instead of

```
target = kwargs.pop('target', bases[0] if bases else object)
```

do

```
target = kwargs.pop('target', bases[:1] if bases else [object])
try:
    target = set(target)
except TypeError:
    target = {target}
```

Now replace every occurrence of `blah == target` (or `blah == xtype` in the wrappers) with `blah in target` (or `blah in xtype`).

Comment: I'm really curious about the downvote. Is there some coding error I missed? I did write this on mobile after all. Perhaps it's late and I spewed some BS by accident?

Comment: This isn't going to do anything for magic methods, and there's a bunch of small errors like `collections.frozenset` or `map(string, ...)`.

Comment: @user2357112. I've fixed that and a couple of other things. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @user2357112. I don't have anything approaching a reasonable testing environment at the moment, so I appreciate your time spent proofreading this.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. I've completely rewritten my answer. It's a lot like yours now, but without the registry or as many special cases.

Comment: @user2357112. I've made major updates and actually tested them.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. I'm done making changes now. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks mostly okay so far. You may want to pass the rest of `**kwargs` to `super().__new__` to support `__init_subclass__`.

Comment: @user2357112. Done. Except the dictionary is always empty because I pop off the ones I care about

Comment: It's empty unless someone passes additional keyword arguments for `__init_subclass__` to use. The `if kwargs` check is currently preventing use with `__init_subclass__` methods that take keyword arguments.

Comment: @user2357112. Gotcha. I've never used that feature before. Thanks for walking me through it. Should be kosher now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I really like how the approach of using class declaration kwargs makes exception an casting explicit. This is a well crafted solution, good job

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. Thank you. This is an idea I had bouncing around in my head for a while now. I appreciate you giving me the motivation to think it through and write it down.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. The only thing that still nags me about this solution is that the default exception list is not the most sensible. I'll update it at some point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe there is no way around this but to sit down and check the dunder methods one by one.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. True, but there are two classes of methods: things like `__len__`, `__index__`, etc., which are used by the "system" and require a very particular return type, and methods like `__add__`, `__lshift__`, etc., which can return whatever. Only the former should be excepted by default, and there shouldn't really be a reason to change that default unless the Python object model gets updated.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just saw you added list of exceptions. That is great job that deserves some credit!

Answer (score 2):

I think using a class decorator with a black list of methods that should not return objects of the same type would be somewhat more Pythonic:

```
class containerize:
    def __call__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, type):
            return self.decorate_class(obj)
        return self.decorate_callable(obj)

    def decorate_class(self, cls):
        for name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, name)
            if callable(attr) and name not in ('__class__', '__init__', '__new__', '__str__', '__repr__', '__getattribute__'):
                setattr(cls, name, self.decorate_callable(attr))
        return cls

    def decorate_callable(self, func):
        def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            return obj.__class__(func(obj, *args, **kwargs))
        return wrapper
```

so that:

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

@containerize()
class ClosedIntContainer(MyInt):
    pass

i = ClosedIntContainer(3) + ClosedIntContainer(2)
print(i, type(i).__name__)
```

would output:

```
5 ClosedIntContainer
```

and that as a bonus the decorator can be selectively used on individual methods as well:

```
class MyInt(int):
    @containerize()
    def __add__(self, other):
        return super().__add__(other)

i = MyInt(3) + MyInt(2)
print(i, type(i).__name__)
```

This outputs:

```
5 MyInt
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, the data model forbids it. And I can prove it to you:

```
>>> class MyClass(ClosedInt, metaclass=type):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         return 'potato'
...     
>>> MyClass(1) + ClosedInt(2)
'potato'
```

Addition is handled by the left hand object first, and if the left type handles it (i.e. does not return `NotImplemented` singleton) then *nothing* about `other` is considered in this operation.  If the right hand type is a subclass of the left-hand type, you could control the result with the reflected method `__radd__` - but of course that is impossible in the general case.

Comment: That would be fine since by definition, closure means if `x` and `y` are of type `T`, then `x + y` is of type `T`. Here `MyClass()` is not of type `ClosedInt`. So the question really applies only if both elements of the operation are of the `ClosedInt` type

Comment: Also can not be done, in general case, and the reason is the same - subclasses can override any behavior of parent.

Comment: @wim. See my attempt. It's not perfect, and of course you can bypass it in a multitude of ways, but I think it'll work if you want to play along.

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to make it *almost* work (I am not the downvoter on your answer, by the way). I just wanted to show that any attempt can be defeated, so this is impossible in the general case.

Comment: I thought I made a clever workaround, but nope. I've added your example to my answer. TIL that you can override the metaclass like that.

Answer (score 1):

I still feel there might be a more *natural* way to accomplish this, but I was able to fix the attempt provided in the question.

Here are the main points that needed ot be fixed.

- We must check methods of all classes in the *mro*, not only the *bases*;
- `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` must be treated as special cases;
- Attributes with `__get__` must be treated separately;
- We have to write a list of exceptions as methods such as `__int__` or  `__eq__` obviously should return their expected types.

### Code

```
import functools

def get_mro(bases):
    # We omit 'object' as it is the base type
    return type('', bases, {}).__mro__[1:-1]

class ClosedMeta(type):
    _register = {}

    # Some methods return type must not change
    _exceptions = ('__int__', '__eq__', ...)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        # A unique id for the class
        uid = max(cls._register) + 1 if cls._register else 0
        mro = get_mro(bases)

        def tail_cast(f):
            """Cast the return value of f"""
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                out = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if type(out) in mro:
                    # Since the class does not exist yet, we will recover it later
                    return cls._register[uid](out)
                return out
            return wrapper

        def deep_tail_cast(f):
            """Cast the return value of f or the return value of f(...)"""
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                out = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if callable(out):
                    return tail_cast(out)
                elif type(out) in mro:
                    return cls._register[uid](out)
                else:
                    return out
            return wrapper

        class PropertyCast:
            """Cast the return value of a property"""
            def __init__(self, prop):
                self.prop = prop

            def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                return cls._register[uid](self.prop.__get__(instance, owner))

            def __set__(self, instance, value):
                return self.prop.__set__(instance, value)

            def __delete__(self, instance):
                return self.prop.__delete__(instance)

        for base in reversed(mro):
            for name, attr in base.__dict__.items():
                if name in ('__getattr__', '__getattribute__'):
                    namespace[name] = deep_tail_cast(attr)
                elif callable(attr) and name not in namespace and name not in cls._exceptions:
                    namespace[name] = tail_cast(attr)
                elif hasattr(attr, '__get__'):
                    namespace[name] = PropertyCast(attr)

        subcls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
        cls._register[uid] = subcls
        return subcls
```

### Example

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __getattr__(self, _):
        return 1

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 2

class ClosedInt(MyInt, metaclass=ClosedMeta):
    pass

x = ClosedInt(2)
print(type(x * x), x * x)
print(type(x.foo), x.foo)
print(type(x.bar), x.bar)
```

### Output

```
<class '__main__.ClosedIntContainer'> 4
<class '__main__.ClosedIntContainer'> 2
<class '__main__.ClosedIntContainer'> 1
```

This still has some issues. By example we still have the tedious task to go through all dunder methods an mark down exceptions to the implemented rules, but unless there is a list of those somewhere, this seems unavoidable.

Comment: You can use the class itself as a key, no need for a uid

Comment: But the class is not created yet

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is writing short codes and meta classes while I barely write a decorator. (damn, lol) But I'm gonna share it anyways.

```
from functools import wraps


class CLOSED:
    _built_ins = [
        '__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__', '__floordiv__',
        '__div__', '__truediv__', '__mod__', '__divmod__',
        '__pow__', '__lshift__', '__rshift__','__and__',
        '__or__', '__xor__',
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def register_closed(method):  # Or you can use type annotations
        method.registered = True  # Or you can add the method names as string to closed decorator
        return method  # In this version you decorate the methods with this

    @staticmethod
    def closed_method(method, cls):
        @wraps(method)
        def wrapper(*a, **kw):
            return cls(method(*a, **kw))

        return wrapper

    @classmethod
    def closed_class(klass, cls):
        for magic in klass._built_ins:
            _method = getattr(cls, magic, False)
            if _method:
                setattr(cls, magic, klass.closed_method(_method, cls))

        for method in dir(cls):
            c1 = method not in klass._built_ins
            c2 = method not in dir(object)
            c3 = getattr(getattr(cls, method), 'registered', False)
            if all((c1, c2, c3)):
                _method = getattr(cls, method)
                setattr(cls, method, klass.closed_method(_method, cls))
        return cls
```

Now after you have this long setup, you just decorate the class as you would normally do;  I am too sleepy to make it work with inherited classes so for now you have to decorate the class that inherits from a closed class.

```
@CLOSED.closed_class
class foo(int):
    @CLOSED.register_closed  # or if you can simply add this to CLOSED.closed_class
    def bar(self, other):    # if you are certain that every method can be casted to its own class
        """Basically just the __add__ method"""
        return self + other


print(type(foo(1) + foo(1))); print(foo(1) + foo(1))  # <class '__main__.foo'> 2
print(type(foo(1).bar(2))); print(foo(1).bar(2))      # <class '__main__.foo'> 3


@CLOSED.closed_class
class baz(foo):
    pass

print(type(baz(1) + baz(3))); print(baz(1) + baz(3))  # <class '__main__.baz'> 4
print(type(baz(1).bar(4))); print(baz(1).bar(4))      # <class '__main__.baz'> 5
```

Feel free to downvote as I'm still not sure if I understood the question correctly.